# "Votes remaining" when closing

Tags: support, closing

I went to vote to close [this thread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5537/so-whats-for-dinner-tonight), and saw at the bottom of the "why close" box that it says 12 votes remaining.  I couldn't really find any info about that number in the FAQ or by searching meta, so I apologize if this has been asked already.

Do I only get 12 votes to close across the life of my account, daily, or does the number refresh at some point (say, every X reputation points).

I ask because I'd rather save my votes to close for questions that aren't so obvious, as I'm sure this one in particular will be closed very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daily.  From the meta.stackoverflow [FAQ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Ffaq&ei=Vi9tTMTLNYG88gbh6fzrCg&usg=AFQjCNEMTIGdEzJ7ui84ThtCRHLQMy4D3A) :

Users with  3000 reputation can cast up to 12  close votes per day. When a question reaches  5 close votes, it is marked as closed, and will no longer accept answers. Closed questions may be opened by casting reopen votes in the same manner. However, you can only vote to close or reopen a question once.

note:  during Beta, the close limit is lower, but the 12 per day limit is the same.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you Ocaasi!

Comment: During our Beta, the vote to close limit is 500. At 2000, I believe that you can use the moderator tools to close instantly, but I'm not popular enough to know for sure. :(  I guess Ocaasi can answer that one...

Comment: @Yossarian.  Ok, I forget when I got the ability to vote to close.  I think at 2000 you can vote to delete.  I'll adjust the question to be sufficiently ambiguous .

Comment: And no, I can't close instantly, but moderators can.

Comment: @Ocaasi, I thought 2000 rep got you access to the moderators tools (in the Beta). I kind of figured you could insta-close from there.

Comment: Hehe, and if you'd checked **our** FAQ rather than stack overflow's, you'd have seen what's going on for us during the beta.  ;o)

Comment: I just realized I had read the Meta FAQ, not the site FAQ, which explains why I couldn't find it (and why Ocaasi probably thought to check the SO FAQ instead).  Derp!  Thanks for the info, all :)